# How to draw a circle according to the offset when drop down the tableView

Tags: ios, pull-to-refresh

1. I know how to draw the circle according to the offset.
2. If i drop down the tableView too fast to see the process of the draw,so i want to make it slower.How to make it? Thanks.

This is my circle.m
property progress is the offset (0.0~1.0).

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [WMFontColor888888 setStroke];
    CGFloat startAngle = - M_PI * 80 / 180;
    CGFloat step = 0.0;
    step = 33 * M_PI/18 * self.progress;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2) radius:self.bounds.size.width / 2 - 3 startAngle:startAngle endAngle:startAngle + step  clockwise:YES];
    path.lineWidth = 1.5;
    path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    path.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;
    [path stroke];

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dig into the layer level, you can subclass `CAShapeLayer` and use `-[CAShapeLayer strokeStart]` and `-[CAShapeLayer strokeEnd]`. Then, you can simply move your CG code into `-drawInContext:`

Example:

```
@implementation MyView

- (Class)layerClass
{
    return [MyCircleLayer class];
}

- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress
{
    MyCircleLayer *layer = (id)self.layer;
    [layer setProgress:progress];
}

@end


@interface MyCircleLayer : CAShapeLayer
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat progress;
@end

@implementation MyCircleLayer

// Vary strokeStart/strokeEnd based on where or how you want to animate the drawing

- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress
{
    _progress = progress;
    /**
      Constantly updating strokeStart/strokeEnd should queue up redraws and
      should draw fluidly, but this could be delayed with an interval or via layer animation
    */
    [self setStrokeEnd:progress];
}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    [WMFontColor888888 setStroke];
    CGFloat startAngle = - M_PI * 80 / 180;
    CGFloat step = 0.0;
    // Draw the full circle
    ...
    [path stroke];
}
```

Comment: I make it like this,but my project crash. -[CALayer setProgre:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17673300

Comment: That's because the view isn't using a layer subclass (hence, the error signifies a plain "CALayer"). You need to either specify a layer subclass or add a MyCircleLayer sublayer to the main view layer and maintain it as a view property.

Comment: Yeah, i make a CircleView and a CircleLayer ,the CircleView is the view which i use in the tableView. But i don't know how to solve it. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: I just want to make my circle like Taobao app. I had no idea about it for two weeks.OMG